# Disk utility volume button is greyed out

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, disk-utility, apfs

I want to store Time Machine backups and backup other files on an external SSD. Upon backing up Time Machine, it doesn't allow me to store any other files on the SSD. I found out that a new partition or volume must be created so that both can be stored. However, I heard that adding a volume is preferable to adding a partition since volumes share space. My problem is that the add volume button is greyed out in Disk Utility. How do I fix this? I already tried running First Aid but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Martha. Can you edit your question to include the version of macOS? Time Machine has changed a bit over the last 5 years even more so than the 5 before that. The steps needed (or lack of options) will depend on the exact version of macOS and if you changed anything on the destination disk

Answer (score 1):

Add will be disabled if you have selected the physical disk. Select the container disk or the existing TM volume instead (assuming the disk is APFS formatted) and you will be able to add another volume alongside in the same container. As you are aware, they will share the free space in the container and this will affect the TM housekeeping and retentions over time.

Ensure `View | Show All Devices` is selected to show the container disk. Then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-Click on the container disk underneath the physical disk and `Add APFS Volume...` The other alternative is to click <kbd>+</kbd> Volume in the toolbar. If your TM volume is encrypted, then this will not apply to your new volume, and you'll need to specify `APFS Encrypted` if you need to in the resulting dialog.

Also worth checking is that the added volume appears automatically in the Time Machine exclusions. Otherwise it will be doing a backup from one vol to another.

Tested on macOS 12.6

Comment: Suggest adding something about Disk Utility: View > Show all devices. Makes it more obvious where the Add will apply (in this case the container).

Comment: Yes, was considering that, esp as there are multiple places to initiate it from.